# Content security policy blocking remote CSS background image

Tags: css, content-security-policy

A background image loaded from a remote server is being blocked by my CSP with the message

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a
>   resource at self ("default-src * https://xxxxx.com"). Source:
>   background-image: url('https://xxxxx....

Here's my CSP:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * https://xxxxx.com; script-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:">
```

...where `xxxxx` is obviously my domain.

I assume it doesn't like `url(...`, but the [CSP spec](https://content-security-policy.com/) doesn't seem to consider `url()` a scheme so I can't see what to do about this. Anyone know?

[UPDATE]

Following @sideshowbarker's comment, I should have pointed out that this call is coming from an inline `style` attribute (not tag).

Comment: Furthermore, shouldn't the `*` allow everything?

Comment: Try changing the Content-Security-Policy header with an img-src of "* data:"

Comment: Same result. What's interesting is the error message suggests it's reading not from `img-src` but from the fallback, `default-src` (which already has the wildcard.)

Comment: This is a real pain, I'm not exactly sure how to go about it if the previous comment didn't work. Good luck.

Comment: Have you tried using `style-src`? The source that message cites is from an inline `style` element, right?

Comment: @sideshowbarker - good point; I should have mentioned this is coming from an inline `style` attribute. The docs say `style-src` governs where external CSS may be loaded from, not background images loaded *by* them.

Comment: @Utkanos OK then I think the solution is to add `style-src 'unsafe-inline'` to your policy. Well, either that or better yet, move that inline style content out to separate file. Anyway, see the answer I added, which goes into it in more detail that I can fit into a comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That CSP violation message indicates you have inline CSS style content, so you must either move that CSS content to a separate file (and use a `link` element to reference it) or else you must specify `'unsafe-inline'`—for example, by adding a `style-src` directive to your policy:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src * https://xxxxx.com;
  script-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
  img-src 'self' https://xxxxx.com data:">
```

The reason is, the CSP violation message cited in the question isn’t saying the image in that CSS style content is the problem—it’s just saying you have some inline style content, period.

And as far as CSP is concerned, it doesn’t matter what the inline style content is—it’s just your existing CSP policy doesn’t allow any inline style content all; your existing policy only allows inline scripts, because `script-src` is the only directive you specified `'unsafe-inline'` for.

So if you’re going to keep that inline style content, you mus use `'unsafe-inline'` to allow it.

**Update:** Based on comments below, it seems that once `'unsafe-inline'` is added for `style-src` in this case, it’s also necessary to add `https://xxxxx.com` for `img-src`.

---

All that said, though, once you’ve ended up specifying `'unsafe-inline'` for both style content and scripts, it seems like you might be at the point where you need to start considering whether you want to specify a CSP policy at all—because allowing everything inline kind of defeats the purpose of having a CSP policy at all to begin with.

If your goal is to reduce XSS risks, it seems you probably should consider moving all your inline style/script content to separate files, and using `<script src>` and `link` to reference those…

Comment: +1 for spotting that my existing `'unsaife-inline` applied to JS only, not CSS. However, adding the `style-src` directive now results in this: "Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://xxxxx.com/my-img.png ("img-src http://192.168.*.* data:")." So it seems it's deferring judgement to `img-src`, not `style-src`

Comment: Oh and I agree re: inline styles/JS - it's not ideal but it's what I have to work with currently. It's a framework.

Comment: OK yeah from that message it sound likes I guess you need to also add `https://xxxxx.com` as a source for `img-src`. I’ve updated the answer to reflect that